# problems navigation 3d p3dx kinect

Tags: ros, navigation, kinect, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used ubuntu 10.10 and ros electric.
I want to navigate with this component but I can't. All the tutorials in 3d are with pr2 robot and the rest of tutorials are in 2d.

I try with this tutorial
http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

But it is for 2d navigation.

I also try with this other
http://ros.org/wiki/3d_navigation

But it is for pr2 robot, and i can't execute it.

I don't know if i can navigate in 3d or i should convert the kinect 3d points in 2d for the navigation.

Can you help me please??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29344/problems-navigation-3d-p3dx-kinect/) by [arroyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1353/arroyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use the kinect PointCloud as the input to the costmaps, it will automatically convert it for 2d navigation. See [costmap_2d](http://ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d) for information on how to add sensor inputs.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0